# How can I use multiple validation rules as base for multiple validation requests in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

Let's say that I have 3 Types of users and they all have common fields for example:
username, email, password .... etc

And each one of them has its own fields, now I create the Add,Update functionality and create the FormRequest for each one of these function which leads me to 6 FormRequest, and they all have common rules for the common fields !

How can I use for example StoreUserRequest and put all the common rules for storing the User and put the individual rules in the right FormRequest, I hope I could explain what I'm trying to achieve clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use traits to accomplish this, this allows multiple classes (the form requests) to inherit the specified shared rules.

Create a `CommonUserRules.php` in `app\Http\Requests` directory:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

trait CommonUserRules
{

    protected function userRules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

This will be the rules that can be shared across multiple form requests.

Then inside the Form Request you use the trait:

```
use CommonUserRules;
```

Then you can append and define your unique rules accordingly:

```
 public function rules()
 {
        return array_merge($this->userRules(), [
            'individual_rule' => 'required',
            'another_individual_rule' => 'required',
        ]);
 }
```